# Class design: Class member inherits from the same base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, class-design

I'm thinking about a proper class design for the following case: Let's say I want to create a class design which resembles (mathematical) functions. All functions derive from base class `Function`. Now one could think of a function `FuncB` which is the sum of multiple objects of `FuncA`. In my case `FuncB` and `FuncA` are rather complicate objects but my current implementation boils down to:

```
class Function
{
    virtual double value() = 0;
};

class FuncA : public Function
{
public:
    virtual double value() {return v;}
private:
    double v;
};

class FuncB : public Function
{
    virtual double value() {
        double result = 0;
        for( auto i : v)
            result += i.value();
        return result;
    }
private:
    std::vector<DerivedA> v;
};
```

Somehow I would consider this as a bad class design since `FuncB` has a member which inherits from the same base class as the class itself. Any suggestions how to solve this more elegant?

Comment: This is the composite design pattern... It's rather well known

Comment: `std::vector<Function*> v;` would be even more useful

Comment: `Somehow I would consider this as a bad class design since FuncB has a member which inherits from the same base class as the class itself.` Why?

Comment: Does it have to be reconfigurable during runtime or do you know at compile time what functions you want to have?

Comment: @molbdnilo to use `accumulate` it is going to have to be `return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0, [](double result, const auto& f){ return result + f.value(); });`. I think I prefer OP's code.

Comment: @user2079303 Not quite sure why ..... Great to hear that this is the way to implement it. I just wanted to hear some opinions on that.

Comment: @StoryTeller if you post you comment as answer, I will accept it

Comment: @hansgans - You can answer your own question, if you like. If you make it a good and complete answer I'll upvote :)

Comment: Will remove my answer if @hansgans posts an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composite design pattern

```
class ContainerOfX : public X {
    typedef X* bestType;
    // maybe...
    // typedef std::shared_ptr<X> bestType;


    ...

    std::vector< bestType > subTypes;
};
```

It allows you to create a drawing system - where a composite object of different shapes can be treated as an agregate

```
obj->draw(); // draw house from various lines and boxes.
```

It allows you to create a simple script of things to do for do/undo logic.